Plotly Python: How to properly add shapes to subplots
How does plotly add shapes to figures with multiple subplots and what best practices are around that?
Let's take the following example:
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True)
fig.add_vrect(x0=1, x1=2, row=1, col=1, opacity=0.5, fillcolor="grey")
fig.add_scatter(x=[1,3], y=[3,4], row=1, col=1)
fig.add_scatter(x=[2,2], y=[3,4], row=2, col=1)


If we add_vrect at the end, the rectangle is visualized as I would expect.
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True)
fig.add_scatter(x=[1,3], y=[3,4], row=1, col=1)
fig.add_scatter(x=[2,2], y=[3,4], row=2, col=1)
fig.add_vrect(x0=1, x1=2, row=1, col=1, opacity=0.5, fillcolor="grey")


Now, when I move away from the dummy example to a more complex plot (3 subplots, multiple y axes, logarithmic scaling, datetime x axis), adding the rectangles last does not help either. I don't manage to visualize them for two of the three subplots.
Thus, I'm trying to better understand how plotly handles this under the hood. From what I have gathered so far, the rectangles are shapes and thus, not part of figure.data, but figure.layout. In the above dummy examples, the shapes are only added to the layout in the second take. Why?
Is it more advisable to use fig.add_shape(type="rect") when working with more complex plots?
Or should I give up and just manually wrangle with fig.layout.shapes instead of using the function calls?
Examples are made with plotly 5.15.0.

The treatment of images in plotly belongs to the layout, so using fig.add_shape(type=‘rect’) would be the same. Shapes can also be drawn using fill=‘toself’ in scatter plots. This is the only comment I can make, as I don't have the code to check your real issue.

The problem with shapes in subplots arises from how plotly assigns axis references (xref and yref). add_vrect automatically maps shapes to subplots using row and col which can fail in complex layouts. For more control, use add_shape.
For a rectangle that always stretches vertically across the entire plot, similar to vrect,  define it with reference to a secondary y-axis. This ensures it remains fixed from top to bottom even when zooming.
Here is an example:
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "time": pd.date_range("2023-01-01", periods=10, freq="D"),
    "value1": [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55],
    "value2": [5, 10, 15, 10, 5, 10, 15, 10, 5, 10],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}], [{}]])

fig.add_shape(
    type="rect",
    x0="2023-01-03", x1="2023-01-06",
    y0=0, y1=1,
    xref="x1",
    yref="y2",
    secondary_y=True,
    fillcolor="blue", opacity=0.3, line_width=0,
)

fig.add_scatter(x=df["time"], y=df["value1"], row=1, col=1, name="Value 1")
fig.add_scatter(x=df["time"], y=df["value2"], row=2, col=1, name="Value 2")

fig.update_yaxes(secondary_y=True, range=[0, 1], fixedrange=True, showgrid=False, visible=False,  row=1, col=1)
fig.update_layout(title="Shapes with Multiple Subplots")
fig.show()





Thanks Serge, much appreciated! Explicitly specifying xref and yref does indeed do the trick. Other than with vrect, the rectangle will be shown independent of whether other traces have been added before or not.
To resolve the vertical "endless" scaling, I have opted for a secondary y-axis on the subplot. I hope you don't mind me editing that into your answer.

@Fabitosh Glad it helped and feel free to change it according to your need. If in the end you find this to be an acceptable answer, do mark it as accepted so it dissppears from the list of unanswered questions. Happy coding!
